# data selector not working in custom Module

Tags: 7, rules, ubercart

I am working in a module and I have added custom date **data** attribute to ubercart order.

Now, I would like to create a **data selector** in rules for custom date attribute of the order.

I have implemented `hook_rules_data_info()` into my custom module but its not showing in data selector in rules.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_data_info().
 */
function uc_datepicker_rules_data_info() {

  $entities['uc_datepicker'] = array(
    'label' => t('Ubercart Delivery Date'),
    'group' => t('Ubercart'),
    'wrap' => TRUE,
    'token type' => FALSE,
  );

  return $entities;
}
```

I have also added implemented `hook_rules_condition_info()` hook and its showing date condition into rules correctly.

Please suggest, how can I add data selector in rules for date attribute of the order in my custom module.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the options as 'getter callback' & 'setter callback'? It seems that these data selectors that you are creating needs to pass the values to the already implemented hook_rules_condition_info as parameters.

Comment: I have not tried with `getter callback` & `setter callback`. I will try.